# Book about monetary union?

Tags: open-economy-macro, books, european-union, optimal-currency-area, monetary-union

do you know any book/manual dealing specifically with monetary unions ? I know economics of monetary union of De Grauwe, but I'm looking for other references.

Thank you

Comment: What specifically are you looking for, DeGrauwe's book is already comprehensive so another textbook would more or less cover the same area. There are a lot of good papers on monetary unions that go into much deeper detail than general textbooks, but no single paper will cover all aspects so what exact topic are you looking at?

Comment: I owuld need maybe a book more technical, dealing with models. De Grauwe is mainly without math.